# Return a value if a PHP GET doesn't exist?

Tags: php, url, get, return-value

I have lots of PHP statements along the lines of:

```
$getvalue = $_GET['valueiwant'];
```

In some scenarios not all variables are available. So, let's say 'valueiwant' doesn't exist in the URL string, how can I return a value based on the fact it doesn't exist?

For example if 'valueiwant' can't be found set $getvalue to -1

Currently it appears the value defaults to 0 and I need to be equal less than 0 if it doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: You're really stuck on this? You've got no ideas whatsoever how this might be done?

Comment: Instead of `isset`/`empty`, use [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use

```
$getvalue=isset($_GET['valueiwant'])?$_GET['valueiwant']:-1;
```

Comment: Perfect, although I prefer `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` because isset will return `false` if the value is null

Comment: @MichelFeldheim `$_GET` data will never contain a null value unless you intentionally inject it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will accept the answer in 5 minutes when I'm allowed!

Comment: @MichelFeldheim: I think $_GET are always of `string` type, even if it is a number. If you want `NULL` you'll get an empty string (length 0).

Answer (score 0):

Use of the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function checks if the offset exists, and returns a boolean value indicating it's existence.

This means that you can structure an if statement around the output.